# View config not found for name "" react native

Tags: react-native

when I'm trying to insert Image into View I get this error

> View config not found for name ""

```
 renderCategory = (category)=>{
    const { Id, Image, Name } = category.item
    const { button, image_category, text_category} = style;
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity style={style.button} onPress={()=>{console.log(Id)}}>
                <View style={{flex:1}}>
               //here the problem
                <Image style={image_category} source={{uri:'https://picsum.photos/150/150'}} /> // when I remove it, it works fine.

                <Text>{Name}</Text>
                </View>
        </TouchableOpacity> 
    ) 
}
render() {
    const { container } = style;
    return (

        <View style={container}>
        <FlatList style={{margin:5}}
            data={this.state.second_categories}
            numColumns={3}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id }
            renderItem={this.renderCategory}
            />

        </View>
    )
}
```

I looked in other post in stackoverflow but nothing solved my issue.

my styles

```
    image_category:{
    width: calcSize(width/4),
    height: calcSize(width/4)
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This issue is due to **overwriting** of the **reserved-word**  `Image`.

```
const { Id, Image, Name } = category.item
```

The `Image` string being used in the below code is from `category.item`, and not the one from `{Image} from 'react-native'`

```
<Image style={image_category} source={{uri:'https://picsum.photos/150/150'}} />
```

Therefore you need to replace the `Image object` in your `category.item` object to something else, that is not a **`react-native`** reserved word to avoid conflicts.

**OR**

*You may make a `stateless component` for the image and use it*

**TLDR**

> Replace the `Image` object in `category.name` to something else as it **conflicts** with `react-native's` tag `Image` or make a `separate component` for the image

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what you have in `image_category` but it must have `width` and `height` https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html